# Can't use an attribute of an item from DynamoDB as a variable to create another item on the same table using NodeJs for AWS Lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I have four types of entities on my table: Clients, Sellers, Products, and Orders. I have the basic CRUD operations for all of them except for Orders.

I need an the price attribute from a product to calculate the finalPrice of the new Order to create it; however, I can't retrieve this attribute within my lambda function to use it.

Here I show my lambda function and how I am trying to retrieve information from a product to create an order.

```
module.exports.createOrder = (event, context, callback) => {
  const clientId = event.pathParameters.PK;
  const sellerId = event.pathParameters.sellerPK;
  const productId = event.pathParameters.productPK;
  const reqBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const orderId = uuidv4();

  const prodParams = {
    Key: {
      PK: `SELLER#${sellerId}`,
      SK: `PRODUCT#${productId}`
    },
    TableName:dataTable
  };

const prodData = db.get(prodParams, function(err, data){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      console.log(data)
    }
  })

  const order = {
    PK: `CLIENT#${clientId}`,
    SK: `ORDER#${orderId}`,
    type: "order",
    sellerId: sellerId,
    productId: productId,
    clientId: clientId,
    orderId: orderId,
    quantity: reqBody.quantity,
    finalPrice: reqBody.quantity * prodData.Item.price
  };

  return db
    .put({
      TableName: dataTable,
      Item: order
    })
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
      callback(null, response(201, order));
    })
    .catch((err) => response(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
};
```

I'm also showing how I'm configuring my pathing on my serverless.yml

```
createOrder:
    handler: handler.createOrder
    events:
    - http:
        path: /client/{PK}/seller/{sellerPK}/product/{productPK}/order
        method: post
        integration: LAMBDA
```

Comment: You say you can't fetch the order, but don't say what happens when you execute this code.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I figured that I needed to use the variable data within the db.get. data.Item.price is what I'm looking to use, but I can't assign it to the finalPrice value for my new Order. I'm thinking that is because of the variable scope. I tried creating a variable in the createOrder function and asign it below the console.log(data) but I never retrieve the value of data.Item.Price outside of that db.get

Comment: Sounds like you aren't getting an error.  Does the console.log(data) after db.get print anything?  If so, what does it contain?

Comment: Well I get an internal server error from the api gateway. If I console.log(data.Item.Attributes) I get exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't use it outside from that else. I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Post the error and the output of the console.log.  It will be a lot easier to help you if we dont have to guess the inputs/outputs of your code.